# What is the limit on the number of transactions waiting for a lock in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, locking

I need to figure out the maximum throughput for updates of the table with a lock, as this is how the current solution is designed.

How many simultaneous updates can be queued internally by SQL server with locking enabled at table or row level?

There was a similar question on MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72119974/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-transactions-that-can-be-queued-up-for-a-row-l. The answer was that the limit (for MySQL) is basically maximum number of simultaneous connections to MySQL server.

Is this the same for SQL Server and can this limit be increased?

Answer (score 3):

You won't hit any such limit.  And it's irrelevant anyway.  If each update requires the same exclusive lock, then the throughput depends on the duration of each transaction holding the lock.

If each transaction lasts 5ms, then your throughput limit is 200 updates/sec.

If each transaction lasts 100ms, then your throughput limit is 10 updates/sec.

etc

Note it's the duration of the transaction containing the UPDATE, not the duration of the UPDATE that is relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server max connections is 32768. Due to the fact that there is internal process, you can have almost more than 32500 connections/session/resquests, all waiting about the same process in the queue when the same data must be updates...

Also there is no limit about locking because the limit is 2147483647 of locks and SQL Server does lock escalation (mutation of page type locks to partition or table lock)

**BUT**

This is the usual behaviour of MS SQL Server, because it works by default in pessimistic model of locks...

**If you activate the optimistic model of locks, there will be no session waiting for de-locking, even if all the sessions want to update the same data...**

Since 2005 version, SQL Server is the only RDBMS that can use both of lockink models : pessimistic and optimistic... And you can mix them too.... !

Comment: Updating the same data concurrently under snapshot isolation: The second updater will block waiting for an X lock, then fail with an update conflict if the first transaction commits (doesn't roll back).